# Memory leak introduced when upgrading from Express 3.4 to 3.20?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks

I have been using Express 3.4 with good success for awhile now.

I am not quite ready to make the jump to Express 4 -- However I figure it would be a good idea to upgrade to the latest version of Express 3 prior to jumping off to 4.

So I upgraded my app to use Express 3.20.

Now:  When I am running my app on express 3.4, the memory usage for each process in pm2 tends to hover around the mid 200, low 300MB range.

As soon as I upgraded to 3.20, the memory usage started climbing over 600MB in less than an hour for each process, at which point things crash out.

Rolling back to 3.4, I have confirmed that memory usage stays level in the mid-200s.

Changing express versions is the only modification I have made.

I am wondering:  Is there a known issue / change of some kind, between 3.4 and 3.20, that could cause a  memory leak?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions for Finding a Memory Leak in an Express Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926648/suggestions-for-finding-a-memory-leak-in-an-express-application)

Comment: I can't comment on the memory leak issue, but I can say that I upgraded a sizable app from express 3 to 4 recently and it was surprisingly straightforward, it took less than an hour. expressjs.com provides a guide that you can use as a checklist: http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html

If you do upgrade before solving this issue I'd be curious to know if you still experience this memory leak in express 4 :)